# http 400 bad request exception for converting json to java object representation

Tags: java, json, spring

When I attempt to send json to server I receive http 400 bad request exception.

The format of the json is :

```
{
    "role": "home",
    "name": "group1: False, group2: False"
}
```

The java class to represent this json is :

```
public class Params {

    private String role;
    private String[] name;

    public String[] getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String[] name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return profileRuleName;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

Is this format of the java class correct in order to represent this json ?

Comment: It seems like `name` should be an array, not a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct an array in JSON like this:

```
{
    "role": "home",
    "name": ["group1","group2"]
}
```

Here's a link to the JSON format that shows arrays (and objects and everything else)

http://json.org

Comment: Wow, you didn't explain the problem but went straight to explaining the solution.

Comment: ok, next time I'll take care of this, thanks for your comment